# Getting internal storage's root path on Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I'm working at a phonegap application with download via filetransfer. Everything's going well as soon as I use a fixed path to my internal storage (/sdcard/ in my case), but this path changes from device to device. I tested in 3 devides until now and the file root is differente in all of them. My question is: there's some way that I can get the root path of the internal storage so I can use it in the filetransfer later?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(URI, function(f){
    var filePath = f.fullPath;
}
```

and pass URI from download callback

Comment: I need the oposite. The f.fullPath at your example should be used to find the local path and then use it to download the file. I tried to use the resolveLocalFileSystemURI but always returns fail (passing 'file:///android_asset/www/index.html' or 'index.html' or a lot of combinations like this as URI)